# Status of videos from the Arf-Kervaire invariant problem conference at MSRI

Tags: soft-question

This is not a real maths question (math-related though). A couple of years ago Mike Hill, Mike Hopkins and Doug Ravenel solved the Arf-Kervaire invariant problem. There was a conference at the MSRI about that (see http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/workshops/show/-/event/Wm547) but all the videos are still in post production.

Does anyone know the status ? I tried to mail msri.org, but they haven't mailed me back (yet).

Edit: Finally got reply from the guys (and galls) at msri. Seems that they are somewhat behind schedule with that videos. Nothing to do about it. There is however one video at the http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/atiyah80.htm site where Mike Hopkins is discussing this very result.

If someone know more videos of conferences on this subject, please let me know.